# Short story identification: Sole inhabitant of desolate planet alternatively regenerated as male / female

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Written in the first person, this lonely human, inhabitant of a desolate and inhospitable planet, desperately searches for another human being who is apparently leaving traces of its existence and movements. This sole human has a type of animal as a pet called Anaximander, who is eventually killed by a predator called, I believe, a dune-runner. At the end of the story it is time for the human to go into some kind of pod to be regenerated and during this process, we learn that the two humans, the searcher and the one sought, are in fact the same being, alternatively regenerated as a man/woman, male/female.

Comment: I've read this - it was in one of the "New Worlds" anthologies, which should help narrow it down.